# A question regarding orthogonal projection that puzzles me a lot. Thanks.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

I encountered a question regarding orthogonal projection. I only have some clues to approach this questions and am not sure whether my thoughts can be used to answer the question. Could anyone check my thoughts and correct it or figure out a better solution, if needed? Thanks in advance.

Suppose $W \subseteq ℝ^6$ is a subspace with basis ${\begin{bmatrix}1\\5\\-1\\6\\787\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-34\\4\\4\\4\\4\\8\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}-5\\123\\-4\\12\\-3\\1\end{bmatrix}}$, and let $P : ℝ^{\color{red}6}\toℝ^{\color{red}6}$ be the orthogonal projection onto $W$. The following do not require very much computation.

1. What is the rank of $P$? How do you know?
  **My thought: the rank will be 4. As a vector in $ℝ^6$ will be projected onto a 4-dimensional subspace, 4 linearly independent columns are needed.**
2. 

What is the dimension of the $1$-eigenspace of $P$? How do you know?
**My thought: the dimension will be 4, too. As $P$ will transform a vector in $ℝ^6$ into the 4-dimensional subspace, the eigenvector should also be on the subspace first so that some linear combinations of the 4 vectors that form $W$ can transform the input vector into the vector itself. Therefore the vector can be represented by W and the dim of the eigenspace is 4.**

What is the dimension of the null space of $P$? How do you know?
**My thought: the dim of null space will be 2. As the dimension is 6 and the rank is 4, the dim of null space will therefore be 2. However, I got stuck here as I tried to image some form of Ax=b that transform a vector x into another b, what A can be so that the x in $ℝ^6$ can be transformed to a vector b that is the projection of A onto $W$.**

Explain why $P$ must be similar to a diagonal matrix, and find a diagonal matrix it is similar to (note: you are *not* being asked to find an invertible matrix $Q$ so that $P = QDQ^{-1}$).

**I have no clues for this one at all, could anyone give me the solution or hint to this one as well?**

Thanks a lot! ^_^

Bump!

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

As you noted

if $v \in W \implies Pv=1\cdot v$

if $u \in W^{\perp} \implies Pu=0\cdot u$

thus, since $\dim(W)=4$ and $\dim(W^{\perp})=2$ we have that $P$ is similar to $diag(1,1,1,1,0,0)$.

Comment: Could you give a more detailed explanation? What is positive or not positive for P? Thanks a lot

Comment: So in this case v is one of the matrix that projects one vector onto the W subspace?

Comment: thus Pv is orthogonal to v

Answer (score 1):

You’ve found an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity 4 and one with geometric multiplicity 2. The sum of their eigenspaces is six-dimensional, so must be all of $\mathbb R^6$. $P$ is therefore diagonalizable and in fact is similar to $\operatorname{diag}(1,1,1,1,0,0)$.

Comment: Maybe $diag(1,1,1,1,0,0)$?

Comment: @gimusi Oops. I was thinking reflection when I wrote that.